# How can bind jquery multiple buttons event in a single function

Tags: jquery

Hope everyone is good. I have a little bit problem of jQuery. I wanna bind multiple events of multiple buttons. Like i have six buttons when i click run1, output will be 1. For run2. output will be 1+2=3, means for run 2 button value 2. and so on for rest of buttons. Simply its a cricket run calculator. six buttons means 1,2,3,4,5,6 runs. when click anyone button, run will added with the previous run. My code is in below. Please help me.

```
var val = 1;
$('#run1').click(function () {
    $('#total_run').html(function (i, val) {
        return val * 1 + 1;
    });
});

$('#run2').click(function () {
    $('#total_run').html(function (i, val) {
        return val * 1 + 2;
    });
});

$('#run3').click(function () {
    $('#total_run').html(function (i, val) {
        return val * 1 + 3;
    });
});

$('#run4').click(function () {
    $('#total_run').html(function (i, val) {
        return val * 1 + 4;
    });
});

$('#run5').click(function () {
    $('#total_run').html(function (i, val) {
        return val * 1 + 5;
    });
});

$('#run6').click(function () {
    $('#total_run').html(function (i, val) {
        return val * 1 + 6;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give them a common class to use as selector and use the current button index for the calculation

```
var $btns = $('.runButtonClass');

$btns.click(function(){
   var index = $btns.index(this);
   $('#total_run').html(function (i, val) {
        return val * 1 + (index + 1);
   });    
});
```